# Load data to report viewer from a DateTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, reportviewer

I have a `DataTable` and as a parameter I want to make a report from it, but it didn't work for me at all...

Anyway, this is an image of my RDLC file:

[image: My Image...]

and this is my code:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.Reset();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc";
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
rprtDTSource.Name = "DataSet1";
rprtDTSource.Value = dt;
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

and that is the error in the Report Form

[image: Error Image...]

Comment: is this using Crystal Reports or another reporting library?

Comment: i don't know i made it like the following 
drag and drop for report viewer >> then design a new report >> name is "DataSet1 ">> then i choose the data source and etc. 
thats how i did it